# Publishing Same Research Paper on a National Conference as well as International IEEE conference

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission, ieee

I submitted my final year research paper for a national level conference as well as international level IEEE conference. I was notified that my research paper has been accepted for the national level conference before 2 weeks ago. And I submitted camera ready papers, registered and ready to present the paper next week on the national level conference.

But yesterday I received a mail from IEEE conference by mentioning my paper is accepted for the conference and asked for camera ready papers based on their template.

Is this situation normal? Can I publish my paper on national level conference as well as international level IEEE conference?

Please note that there will be proceedings for both conferences.

Comment: Did you at any point promise to any one of these conferences that you had not submitted this work anywhere else?

Comment: No. I didn't promised to any of those conferences.

Comment: Did either conference explicitly forbid simultaneous submission to another publication venue?  (Most CS conferences include such a clause in their calls for papers.)

Comment: @JeffE no there were no such clause in both conferences.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot publish the same paper at these two conference. For an IEEE conference publication, you have to transfer copyright on the paper to the IEEE, which precludes publication in another proceedings.

You shouldn't have submitted the same paper to two places simultaneously. It's clearly against ethical standards in academics. It is not your fault, if there wasn't a clear indication on the conference submission site, and your advisor hasn't intervened (he should have). Still you have to deal with the consequences now.

And the consequences are that you have to withdraw your paper from one of these conferences. If you have the choice, it would probably be better to withdraw from the national conference. Call yourself lucky if you don't get into deeper trouble from this.

Comment: it is too late to withdraw paper from the national conference now. because I have already registered for it.
Is it ok if I make considerable modification to the research paper when I submit camera ready papers to the IEEE conference?

Comment: @KanishkaDilshan: Definitely not unless you get explicit permission from the program committee.  They accepted it as original, unpublished research, rather than a revised/modified version of a previously published paper.  (Any modifications big enough to make it truly different would also make it no longer the paper they accepted.)  Most likely they would no longer be interested in it under such circumstances, and definitely you cannot assume they would be.  (However, I would suggest withdrawing it rather than asking, because asking them emphasizes the issue of simultaneous submission.)

Answer (score 1):

In Japan, they have a loophole for this, and is based on what Silvado mentioned on preclusion. They basically say in the website that the conference is not indexed, and they only give handouts and digital proceedings with no ISBN number.

The document the IEEE holds the copyrights of is the document you have submitted after doing all of the modifications the reviewers suggested, that is the reason some authors get to publish their papers in their own webpages, as long as it is not the same document.

I would advice against doing any modifications to any of the papers, since it has already been accepted and it is not the papers the reviewers choose, it would be unethical and you can get in more trouble.

I do agree that you should withdraw one of the papers.

Edit: I forgot that the IEEE updated its copyright policies, you actually cannot do that anymore

Comment: The copyright stuff in the second paragraph is not right.  There is no general copyright exception for using the version before modifications based on reviews, and the IEEE copyright transfer covers both versions.  However, clause 8 of the retained rights section of the IEEE copyright form at http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecopyrightform.pdf allows posting of preprints under certain limitations.

Comment: You are right, this was under the old policy, I remember there was a big fuzz about this. Thanks for the clarification: http://www.ieee.org/documents/authorversionfaq.pdf