# Can we submit our research paper for review at two IEEE conferences simultaneously?

Tags: publications, conference, ethics

Can we send our research paper to two IEEE conference simultaneously, and then after acceptance, decide which conference proceedings to publish it in?

Comment: Related question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/publishing-same-research-paper-on-a-national-conference-as-well-as-international - However, that question deals with whether one may publish a paper in two conferences, while this question deals with whether one may submit a paper for review to two conferences with the intent of withdrawing one later.

Answer (score 29):

### No.

It is considered unethical in the academic community to submit a paper for simultaneous review at multiple venues (unless it is explicitly permitted by the publications, *and* you disclose this on submission).

The [IEEE guidelines](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/rights/Section_822F.html) on multiple submission prohibit multiple simultaneous submissions:

> Authors should only submit original work that has neither appeared elsewhere for publication, nor which was under review for another refereed publication.

The [guidelines further specify](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/rights/Section_822F.html) that failure to disclose, on submission, that the work is under review for another publication, can result in (after multiple offenses)

> suspension of publication privileges in all IEEE Publications for 1 year and rejection and return of all papers by the author(s) that are currently in review or in any IEEE publication's queue (papers may be re-submitted after suspension term has expired).

In addition, engaging in this practice can irreparably damage your reputation in the academic community.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes, but it is unethical. Even when you read the agreement before submitting your paper it appears that the work should be original, that means that it should have not been submitted to other conference or journal.
You must put in the shoes of the reviewers, in one hand you make them waste time by reviewing one paper that is already being checked up in another conference. Also you are getting one available spot that could be filled by another research paper by another person.

One advice, take your work in academia more seriously than just submitting like if its a game.

Answer (score -2):

I understand your motivation, because IEEE only looks into how to protect reviewers even though many of them are not competent or up to the level of the submitted manuscript. Such incompetent reviewer will normally  ask for pointless revision or may reject the paper if s/he doesn't understand the paper main idea and contribution even though the other reviewers of the paper could praised it and accepted it.

Such incompetent reviewers  usually will not understand the paper because they accept reviewing papers that are not within their subdomain or area of expertise to just adding service part to their CVs.

Unfortunately  IEEE has a serious problem in its current procedures of selecting reviewers which is done randomly, and that means the editor will look into the reviewers pool of the journal and sends some invitations randomly for possible reviewers. The issue will be exaggerated when that reviewer accept and judge your work regardless of whether they are qualifying for that or no. Unfortunately, they can hurt you by judging wrongly your work and escape simply because their identity  are protected by the Journal.

Also, IEEE has no real commitment to any time span of the reviewing process, they may announce the reviewing process takes three months for example, but actually they may let you stuck awaiting for the decision much more time. Therefore, IEEE violates what it should be a fair process for publication in many dimensions, and if your paper received three reviewers decision, for example two acceptance and one rejection, IEEE Editors normally go with the rejection and neglect the majority decision  opposite to any fair judgment system . They should go with the majority of reviewers decisions but unfortunately they don't. So I can't say it is not possible solution to overcome such a pain by trying for multiple submission because you also can't put your future under such messy, uncertain and unfair  circumstances.  You can be a student who needs one more paper for graduation, or you can be a faculty needs one more paper for promotion, or you can be a graduate student needs one more paper to get hired  or to keep your position, and if you lost that chance of publication on time  because of some incompetent reviewers then the impact could be huge on your life.

Those incompetent reviewers are actually very bad people who may destroy other people life and career just to add some lines in their CVs reflect their service as reviewers for journal x or y.

I don't encourage you to violated any journal rules, but act in a smart way, and don't make mistakes can be taken against you. On the other hand  protect your self from such possible unfair environment. try to search  for journals or conferences that accept multiple submission.

The process of submit paper should be similar to the process of sending applications for admission to universities. So you are able to send multiple applications to many universities  but in the end of the day you will accept only one offer when offers come. IEEE should also do the same to protect authors for wasting time and efforts, but unfortunately they don't.

Therefore, do what is best for you because publishers especially IEEE only care about their regulations and reviewers and their CVs update with the editorializing or reviewing service.  Your career growth and future plans  for sorry is not among their concerns at all.

Comment: Without paragraph breaks, this is incredibly hard to read.

Comment: Could you clarify your statement that IEEE editors choose reviewers randomly? Is the probability distribution uniform across the whole "pool" of reviewers, or is it strongly peaked near the topic of the paper? If you're saying it's uniform (or close to uniform), could you provide evidence to support that claim?

Comment: Randomly means, no data to validate reviewer credibility except the reviewer claiming of his ability to judge a paper.  So the system itself is working on non reliable reviewer pool.  Therefore, if a reviewer accept an invitation, the editor has no clue whether he could give right or wrong judgement. The evidence of that is the discrepancy between reviewers decision. Some accept the paper and others reject it. If who accepted are right  then the who rejected  are selected  randomly,  and if who reject it are right then who accept it are selected randomly randomly.

Answer (score -6):

IEEE allows certain authors to submit and publish work that is currently under review.

IEEE likewise allows certain authors to submit and publish work that was previously published.

IEEE likewise allows certain authors to submit and publish work that was published by other persons.

Numerous examples can be found by searching the web.

Comment: It would be better to provide some references (links) where IEEE mentions these stuffs.

Comment: When you say "certain" author, what exactly do you mean? Do these author possess some special characteristics?