# How long does it take for a manuscript to get accepted in the International Journal of Surgery?

Tags: publications, research-process, journals

I sent my short communication almost a month back, but have still not received a response. There's a high chance it might get rejected, and my colleagues are asking me to submit it to another journal. If it gets accepted by the other journal, than I can just retract my submission from IJS.

Can someone guide me? I'm scared that the topic I chose might get picked out and published by someone else. Do I contact the journal regarding this?

Comment: "If it gets accepted by the other journal, than I can just retract my submission from IJS." This is unethical. Don't do that, it might get you blacklisted by both journals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is my paper under review (or similar) for too long and if yes, how should I react?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/88355/7734) and [How is it in my best interest not to submit a paper to two journals simultaneously?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28086)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know what's happening to your manuscript, the best (and possibly only) way to do so is to write to them and ask. I note [their website](https://www.ijsurgery.com/index.php/isj) gives the email address of the editorial office; they are the people you want to write to.

One thing you really should not do is submit your paper to another journal before withdrawing it from IJS, because if you do that then you are likely [in breach of dual submission rules](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28086/how-is-it-in-my-best-interest-not-to-submit-a-paper-to-two-journals-simultaneous) at both journals. That can get you blacklisted by both publishers.