# Can we present a same study to a different conferences?

Tags: conference, presentation

I was wondering if it is ok to present the same paper (may be already published in journals or unpublished) in different conferences? Assuring that the conference will not publish the whole research work but only abstracts in the proceedings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we submit our research paper for review at two IEEE conferences simultaneously?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18438/can-we-submit-our-research-paper-for-review-at-two-ieee-conferences-simultaneous)

Comment: @Coder: Not a duplicate. This question is about presenting on (possibly non-publishing) conferences. The other question is about submission for review to two publishing venues. Two entirely different things.

Comment: @Coder it is entirely different from the other question. My point here is, I want to present a same study, data (but of course may have modified the title and some part of the presentation) from one conference to another. Another point is my paper is already published but I want to present the findings in a conference.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper However, the answers could definitely well be interpreted relating to the present question from the duplicate question. Anyway, I have retracted my close vote. Thanks.

Comment: Might clarify field. In physics, chemistry, and engineering near to these fields, it wouldn't be an issue necessarily. (People in a group might present same work (or work that just was recently published) to different conferences in order to expose work to different sub-area audiences and to have chances to discuss.  (the short Abstracts can look pretty identical although perhaps geared to different audiences) I would assume this is typical for fields with conferences without proceedings (or that have option of submitting to a conference proceedings that isn't used by majority).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the rules of the conference, but it is usually OK. You could get different input from different audiences. 
Beware of publishing rights if there are published proceedings and you expect the paper to be published in a Journal that expects original and never before published before material.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the field. For example my supervisor (in computer science) tends to give the presentations on our software project using the same theoretical core, but each time this core is supported by different evaluation benchmarks. In my opinion I do not see anything wrong in presenting the same ideas on different conferences, especially if it is not published and one does not try to present it as completely novel work. Diversity of presentation venues facilities better work dissemination after all.